# drupal 7 file upload not updating latest file

Tags: files

When I upload a file for the first time, it would use the same name as the one on my hard disk. If later I modify the file contents but keep the same name and upload it again, drupal adds a suffix like "_0", _1" and so on.

Later when trying to get the real file name saved I only get the file name with suffix "_0" even though the latest uploaded file was named "_3".

what could be wrong?

Regards

Comment: That can happen when files go missing from the disk, but their entries are still in the `file_managed` table. Writing a small script to query the data in that table against the file system would probably show you which specific files are the problem

Comment: another possibility (depending on how you are getting the real file name - for which you don't specify or provide any details) is simply the Drupal cache, or browser cache.  I had a similar problem with Chrome, where I had to keep clearing the browser cache for it to recognize the latest file... it appeared to be caching only parts of a page and refusing to recognize the change.